# Struts2 textfield display length

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I would like to make Struts2 textfield can display only 10 words but accept 20 words. See sample;

Want to display

```
1234567890
```

Want to accept

```
12345678901234567890
```

If I enter

```
1234567890123
```

And also want to display in textfield is 1234567890.Please share me some ideas and links

Answer (score 2):

You can create your struts 2 text field which will accept max 20 character like below.

Code:

```
<s:textfield maxlength="20" id="my" value=""></s:textfield>
```

for dispaly only 10 digit you need to use javascript or jquery like below code.

Jquery Code:

```
var value = "12345678912345678912";
$('#my').val(value.substr(0,10));
```

if value is not an String then you can use.

```
var value = 12345678912345678912;
$('#my').val(value.toString().substr(0,10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this code you can achieve it

```
<s:textfield name="fieldname" value="12345678901234567890" size="10"/>
```

the display area of the field not exceed a 10 characters. However, the filed can contain more than 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fixed Size, for Example:

```
<input type="text" value="12345678901234567890" style="width:50px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ex: input type="text" value="12345678901234567890" style="width:50px" maxlength="20"